# Replace text in a textarea on button click

Tags: jquery, replace, textarea

I'm trying to add a textarea to the sidebar where users can convert text to numbers on button click.

The code is in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DF5Xf/

When I click on the button nothing changes... Is there something that I need to change in the code to make it work?

I have spent an hour looking for a solution...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, you just needed to change the framework on the left to jQuery. :)

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DF5Xf/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

You have MooTools selected not jQuery on the side bar

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/DF5Xf/1/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code works, you just forgot to load jQuery in your fiddle. Here is the modified version:

http://jsfiddle.net/NvNYL/